# Can you extract var name from interpolated expression with template literals?

Tags: javascript

If I have a var like

```
myVar = `Some text with ${eggs} and ${noodles} or ${pies}`;
```

Is there any way to get myVar as an unprocessed string before var substitution, basically "Some text with ${eggs} and ${noodles} or ${pies}"?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to dynamically generate an array with the var names (eggs, noodles, pies) inside. I've got many different myVars and I want to avoid having to explicitly type the arrays out.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can not take the variables back out of the literal string.

Instead of using a fixed set of variables, I suggets to use a dynamic approach with an array, or an other structured data organisation.

```js
var getText = (...a) => `Some text with ${a[0]} and ${a[1]} or ${a[2]}`;

console.log(getText('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
console.log(getText('eggs', 'noodles', 'pies'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, I ended up using strings instead of sting literals, and extracting variables with regex as follows:

```js
const str = "my name is ${name} and I like to play ${sport}";
const variables = str.match(/\${\w*}/g);
console.log(variables)
```